# Casas decimais ao usar Println em Java

Tags: java

Estou com o seguinte problema quando mando imprimir essa função

```
System.out.println("Area do Tetraedro =  " + c1.getArea());
```

o valor dela e muito grande, exemplo:

> Area do Tetraedo = 389.71143170299734

Como deixá-lo com duas casas decimais? E também, como colocar a unidade de medida no final?

Comment: Não entendi a parte que você fala sobre unidade de medida, poderia explicar o que precisa?

Comment: no final teria que sair assim olha

Comment: Area do Tetraedo = 389.71 Kg

Comment: area em kilogramas?

Comment: era exemplo mas ja resolvi aqui valeu

Comment: Área de um objeto 3D, e em kg... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já resolveu, mas poderia utilizar a classe `DecimalFormat` do pacote `java.text`. Ela possui o método `format()` que recebe um decimal e formata como você desejar.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o `printf()` ao invés do `println()`. Exemplo:

```
System.out.printf("Area do Tetraedro =  %.2f\n", c1.getArea());
```

Onde `%.2f` que dizer que o segundo argumento do método, ou seja, o primeiro depois da String, será representado como um número de ponto flutuante limitado a mostrar apenas duas casas decimais.

O `\n` faz o papel de quebrar a linha, que fazia o `println()` e que o `printf()` não faz automaticamente.

Comment: A versão atualizada da linguagem aponta %.2f como erro de sintaxe, para funcionar troquei o ponto pela vírgula.