# Como reduzir um número decimal em java?

Tags: java, android

Por exemplo...
Calculando 8/6 terei uma dízima periódica com valor igual a 1,333333... Porém só quero mostrar ao usuário apenas 2 dígitos depois da vírgula, ou seja, 1,33. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16276/101 resolvem o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Já achei a resposta.

É só utilizar o `DecimalFormat`, assim:

```
double x = 1.3333;
DefimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0,##");
df.format(x);
```

Comment: Dê o aceite na sua própria resposta então para indicar que a pergunta foi solucionada.

Comment: Aceitar própria resposta só após dois dias, @Everton.