# Dúvida virgula, casas decimais Java

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com algumas dúvidas, poderiam me ajudar por gentileza.

Primeiro: Ao inserir o valor de entrada. Digite o salário do primeiro funcionário: 12854,89
EU NÃO CONSIGO COLOCAR VÍRGULA PARA ADICIONAR O VALOR NÚMERICO.

Segundo: Ao gerar o valor da média(double), como eu faço para ter somente duas casas decimais após a virgular/ponto.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16276/112052 - aproveitando, clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Agradeço a dica sanou uma de minhas duvidas. 

Saberia me dizer
Primeiro: Ao inserir o valor de entrada. Digite o salário do primeiro funcionário: 12854,89 EU NÃO CONSIGO COLOCAR VÍRGULA PARA ADICIONAR O VALOR NÚMERICO.

Este valor eu só consigo adicionar se houver o ponto(.), se houver virgula(,) consta como erro.

Comment: A [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) diz que `parseDouble` usa as mesmas regras de `valueOf`, que por sua vez só aceita o ponto. Se quer a vírgula, tem que usar [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html). Ex: https://ideone.com/zG4sP8

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte colocar o %.2f --> esse "2" é o número de casas decimais que você seleciona no print ou seja:

System.out.printf("A = %.2f%n",média);