# Gostaria de mostrar 3 casas depois da vírgula

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1, n2 , es;
        
        System.out.println("Progrma - Calculadora");
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro número:");
        n1 = leitor.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Digite seu segundo número:");
        n2 = leitor.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Informe de acordo com opcões abaixo que ira usar:" +
                "\n 1 - Somar" +
                "\n 2 - Subtrair" +
                "\n 3 - Dividir"+
                "\n 4 - Multiplicar");
        System.out.print("Escolha quais das opcões acima:");
        es = leitor.nextInt();
        
        if (es == 1){
            System.out.print("A soma entre " + n1 + " e " + n2 + " é " + (n1 + n2) );
        }
        if (es == 2){
            System.out.print("A subtração entre "+ n1 + " e " + n2 + " è " + (n1 - n2));
        }
        if (es == 3){
            System.out.print("A divisão entre " + n1 + " e " + n2 + " é " + (n1/n2);
        }
        if (es == 4){
            System.out.print("A multiplicação entre " + n1 + " e " + n2 + " è " + (n1*n2));
        }
```

Minha duvida é es == 3, pois quando eu divido  25/50 aparece 0.0 em vez de 0.5

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Casas decimais ao usar Println em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16276/casas-decimais-ao-usar-println-em-java)

Comment: Ao dividir dois inteiros, o resultado é truncado. Se quer as casas decimais, use `double` em vez de `int`. Depois, para controlar a quantidade de casas decimais, veja o link que o Augusto indicou acima

Answer (score -1):

Você pode deve trabalhar com double ao invés de int.

Pois, o int é inteiro, onde ele vai trabalhar com números inteiros, positivos e negativos, 0,1,2,3,4....
Já o double é para números reais, onde a precisão do double é de 10 casas decimais. 1.000000001, 2.0000000001.....

utilize o .nextDouble() ao invés do .nextInt()

```
System.out.println("Progrma - Calculadora");
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro número:");
        n1 = leitor.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Digite seu segundo número:");
        n2 = leitor.nextDouble();
```

ou então na divisão use SUAINT.doubleValue(), para converter de int para double, ficando:

```
System.out.print("A divisão entre " + n1 + " e " + n2 + " é " + (n1.doubleValue()/n2.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Na verdade um `double` suporta mais que 10 casas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9999221

Answer (score -2):

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n1, n2, es;

    System.out.println("Programa - Calculadora");
    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite o primeiro número:");
    n1 = leitor.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o segundo número:");
    n2 = leitor.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Informe de acordo com opções abaixo que irá usar:" +
            "\n 1 - Somar" +
            "\n 2 - Subtrair" +
            "\n 3 - Dividir" +
            "\n 4 - Multiplicar");
    System.out.print("Escolha quais das opções acima:");
    es = leitor.nextInt();

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

    if (es == 1) {
        System.out.printf("A soma entre %d e %d é %d%n", n1, n2, (n1 + n2));
    } else if (es == 2) {
        System.out.printf("A subtração entre %d e %d é %d%n", n1, n2, (n1 - n2));
    } else if (es == 3) {
        // Utilizando a classe DecimalFormat para exibir 3 casas decimais
        double resultado = (double) n1 / n2;
        System.out.printf("A divisão entre %d e %d é %s%n", n1, n2, df.format(resultado));
    } else if (es == 4) {
        System.out.printf("A multiplicação entre %d e %d é %d%n", n1, n2, (n1 * n2));
    }
}
```

}